# JAVA_HOME error in Sonar Scanner for MSBuild

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have set up a sonar scanner MSBuild in Jenkins, but suddenly I'm getting below error.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME exists but does not point to a valid Java home
       folder. No "\bin\java.exe" file can be found there.
```

Below is Environment variable for Java Jdk

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
```

How to solve this Issue?

Comment: More Information: I am getting this error only for **Sonar Scanner for MsBuild - End Analysis** task only in Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I have added **"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2"** as value of **JAVA_HOME** environment Variable and its working. I don't know exactly this is the correct solution OR Not, but when I have checked **sonar-scanner.bat** file then it's taking %JAVA_HOME%/bin/java.exe location of Java.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a file at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java.exe.

If yes then I'd wager there is quoting issue in the SonarQube or the MSBuild task that does not like the space in the path.
Install your java in a path without a space that will likely help

If No, well...  you just found your problem !

Comment: Yes "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java.exe." exist.  A few days back it was working fine, suddenly I am getting this error.